# Mongoid grouping over multiple embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have some documents with roughly the following structure:

```
{
 "_id": "derp",
  "name": "thing",
  "animal": {
    "_id": "abc",
    "stuff": [
      "blah",
      "wah"
    ]
  },
},
{
  "_id": "nerp",
  "person": {
    "_id": "bc",
    "enough": [
      "lah",
      "ah",
      "mwah"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm looking to count the rows in the arrays "stuff" and "enough". I was initially thinking that I could do something with unwind, but if I call it once for each embedded document, "person" and "animal", then I will be stuck with nothing.

I ended up doing seperate queries to get the counts of each inner array of "stuff" and "enough", but I would like to do it all in one query.

Does anyone know how I would go about getting the count for each of these and then putting them in a seperate field like "object_count"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat and question update - this is working solution on test data set:

```
var unwind = {
    $unwind : "$array"
}
var project = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        array : {
            $cond : [{
                    $ne : ["$a", []]
                }, "$a", "$b"]
        }
    }
}

var group = {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        a : {
            $push : "$animal.stuff"
        },
        b : {
            $push : "$person.enough"
        }
    }
}
var group2 = {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        sum : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}

db.info.aggregate([group, project, unwind, unwind, group2])
```

Main idea is to put all stuff into one array, then unwind (as we are pushing then we need to unwind twice) and finally count.

Comment: Hrm...Actually, I thought that worked but moped is saying "exception: invalid operator '$size'

Comment: What version of mongo do you have?

Comment: I have version 2.6.3 so $size should work. I have to look into this a little more to see.

Comment: @unflores - could you check query via mongo shell? Also maybe driver is outdated?

Comment: I double checked directly in mongo of of the data I had listed, I'm still getting the error for $size.  Also, I realize that my originaly listing of the db structure was incorrect. I updated it. I was thinking that I could potentially project somehow, but $size is giving me the same error.

Comment: @unflores - could you provide expected document structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114485/discussion-between-unflores-and-profesor79).